# chrome is stuck on the old last contract that I deployed

Tags: truffle, metamask

when I deploy a contract (on the local net )with truffle, I can't interact with it on the browser, on the browser I see an old contract that I deployed in the past.
when I go to the console and do

```
console.log(contractInstance.methods)
```

I get the methods of the old contract , and when I do this

```
console.log(contractInstance._address)
```

I get the address of the current smart contract.

I tried rebooting the PC, testing on another browser, rebuilding the .json file, deploying a different smart contract .... but I still get that old smart contract in the browser.

TIP:
on ganache in the contract section I see that the current smart contract has been deployed successfully, the address is the same as the address of the smart contract that I just deployed

the contractInstance is created like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.ethereum.enable().then(function(accounts){
      contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(window.abi, "0x9fDc28ffAd66B8BA9dBC883524A8E4F0309cD25c", {from: accounts[0]});
    });
});
```

Comment: How is `contractInstance` created? From your description it is very likely the webpage isn't reflecting the changes correctly.

Comment: @Ismael

so you mean that sometimes this works other times it doesn't?

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.ethereum.enable().then(function(accounts){
      contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(window.abi, "0x9fDc28ffAd66B8BA9dBC883524A8E4F0309cD25c", {from: accounts[0]});
    });
    
});

Comment: I guess that 0x9fdc is the new address. How does window.abi is initialized? You can edit the question to add the details.